# User input values for a Rectangle

Tags: java, syntax, geometry, java.util.scanner, rectangles

I have a class where a user inputs the x and y coordinates for the top left corner of a perfect rectangle, as well as the length and width. The RectangleViewer constructor sets the rectangle as null and then sets all the variables to 0.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class RectangleViewer {
    private Rectangle rectangle;
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public RectangleViewer() {
        this.rectangle = null;
        this.rectangle = new Rectangle(new Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0), 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    public void inputRectangleParameters() {
        System.out.print("Please enter the x coordinate of the top left point of the rectangle: ");
        double xCoordinate;
        xCoordinate = input.nextDouble();
    
        System.out.print("Please enter the y coordinate of the top left point of the rectangle: ");
        double yCoordinate;
        yCoordinate = input.nextDouble();
    
        System.out.print("Please enter the length of the rectangle: ");
        double inputLength;
        inputLength = input.nextDouble();
    
        System.out.print("Please enter the width of the rectangle: ");
        double inputWidth;
        inputWidth = input.nextDouble();
    }

    public void initializeRectangle() {
        this.rectangle = new Rectangle(new Point2D.Double(inputRectangle());
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Rectangle class itself:

```
public class Rectangle {
    private double width;
    private double length;
    private Point2D.Double topLeftPoint;

    public Rectangle(Point2D.Double topLeftPoint, double width, double length) {
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
        this.topLeftPoint = topLeftPoint; 
    }
```

How would I set it up so that the values that are put in inputRectangleParameters are assigned to a rectangle that will be created in initializeRectangle?

Answer (score 0):

The method `inputRectangleParameters` reads values from the command line. If you wish to create the rectangle in the `initializeRectangle` method, the read values need to be passed to it.

This could be done by e.g. returning the values in an object.
As the Rectangle class contains according attributes for the values, I'd recommend to create a rectangle object within the input method and returning it to initialize.

```
public Rectangle inputRectangleParameters() {
    System.out.print("Please enter the x coordinate of the top left point of the rectangle: ");
    double xCoordinate;
    xCoordinate = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Please enter the y coordinate of the top left point of the rectangle: ");
    double yCoordinate;
    yCoordinate = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Please enter the length of the rectangle: ");
    double inputLength;
    inputLength = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Please enter the width of the rectangle: ");
    double inputWidth;
    inputWidth = input.nextDouble();

    return new Rectangle(new Point2D.Double(xCoordinate,yCoordinate),inputWidth,inputLength);
}

public void initializeRectangle() {
    this.rectangle = inputRectangleParameters();
}
```

A less clean version would be to return e.g. an array of the values with specific positions of values.

```
public double[] inputRectangleParameters() {
    System.out.print("Please enter the x coordinate of the top left point of the rectangle: ");
    double xCoordinate;
    xCoordinate = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Please enter the y coordinate of the top left point of the rectangle: ");
    double yCoordinate;
    yCoordinate = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Please enter the length of the rectangle: ");
    double inputLength;
    inputLength = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Please enter the width of the rectangle: ");
    double inputWidth;
    inputWidth = input.nextDouble();

    return new double[]{xCoordinate, yCoordinate, inputWidth, inputLength};
}

public void initializeRectangle() {
    final double[] rectangleParameters = inputRectangleParameters();
    this.rectangle = new Rectangle(new Point2D.Double(rectangleParameters[0], rectangleParameters[1]), rectangleParameters[2], rectangleParameters[3]);
}
```

Comment: Theoretical question: How would you do this if both inputRectangleParameters and initializeRectangle were void methods?

Comment: By storing the values e.g. as class attributes. For the example with the array by adding 
private double[] rectangleParameters; as class attribute and setting it like this: this.rectangleParameters = new double[]{xCoordinate, yCoordinate, inputWidth, inputLength};